# reactjs typescript - DOM reference documentation

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I am playing with reactjs and typescript. In order to go forward, I would appreciate a document refence od React.DOM object. Having this, I could create the definition of the object and so forth use the intellisense, compilation control, ...

Do you have a link to React.DOM reference object?

Thank in advance

Comment: If found a usefull link but http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html to play with the JSX compiler. But any link on the React.DOM reference will be appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the Dart bindings of React. They should contain what you are looking for.

https://github.com/cleandart/react-dart/blob/master/lib/react.dart

For the list of attributes

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1783e54eb0158c85b15e19846a6e153e39b265bf/src/dom/DefaultDOMPropertyConfig.js